# Convert 'crontab' commands into pythonic terms

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to use the `datetime` module to work in a similar fashion as the crontab within Linux.
Currently in my crontab, I am writing it as follows:

```
*/15 0-7 * * 1-6 python /user_data/my_code.py # Run every 15 mins between 12am-7am
*/5 8-17 * * 1-6 python /user_data/my_code.py # Run every 5 mins between 8am-5pm
*/10 18-20 * * 1-6 python /user_data/my_code.py # Run every 10 mins between 6pm-8pm
*/5 21-23 * * 1-6 python /user_data/my_code.py # Run every 5 mins between 9pm-11pm
```

The reason that I am unable to implement this crontab because I am making a few changes in my_code.py and I would not want to
create a few scripts so as to write the above crontab scenarios

Eg. in a code portion of `my_code`

```
def check_for_tasks(seconds):
    ...

# Run the following between 12am-7am if the task is more than 100 seconds
check_for_tasks(100)
# Run the following between 8am-5pm if the task is more than 80 seconds
check_for_tasks(80)
# Run the following between 6pm-8pm if the task is more than 50 seconds
check_for_tasks(50)
# Run the following between 9pm-11pm if the task is more than 150 seconds
check_for_tasks(150)
```

Is it possible to 'convert' crontab into pythonic terms?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

> Python job scheduling for humans.
>
> An in-process scheduler for periodic jobs that uses the builder pattern for configuration. Schedule lets you run Python functions (or any other callable) periodically at pre-determined intervals using a simple, human-friendly syntax.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the article, it certainly looks great! But is there a way to achieve this without installing any new modules?